# How to calculate the expected value of random graph generation

Tags: algorithm, probability

Hello this is my first question. I met a homework in algorithm and probability that I can't find a clue to calculate.

Question:
Computing Number of Triangles in a Graph: Given an undirected graph G = (V, E), a triangle in G is a clique of size 3 (formally, a set of nodes {u, v, w} is a triangle in G if (u, v), (v, w), (u, w) are all edges of G). Consider the following algorithm for approximating the number of triangles in a graph. First construct a sampled graph G' = (V, E') as follows. The vertex set of G' is same as that of G. For every e ∈ E, put e in E' with probability p (think of p as, say, 0.1). In this new sampled graph G', count the number of triangles and let T' be the number of triangles in G' (assume that you have given a black box subroutine to count the number of triangles in G' ). Then output T̃= T'/p.
Show that the expected value of T̃=T ,T is the triangle number of original graph G.

I am confusing that the edge in G or G' to form a triangle is not independent since two adjacent triangles in G might share the edge. And not the all the pair of vertices in G can form a edge in G', only those edges are in G will be present in G' with p. It's hard for me to think of the relationship of number of edges and number of triangles in G or G'.

Hope someone can give me some hints, even not the whole solution is OK.

Comment: _"For every e ∈ E, put e in E' with probability p (think of p as, say, 0.1)"_ What would it mean that an edge has probability p? Probability of what? What would the random variable be? Is p a constant for all edges in E'?

Comment: OK, I think I get it, is it  the probability of e being included in E'? So for every edge e in E, theres a probability p of it being part of E'?

Comment: p of certain edge e is that for one edge e ∈ E, the probability this edge is also present in G'. And we want to get the expected value of T̃, T̃ is defined as  T'/p. Here T' is the triangle number in G'.

Answer (score 0):

> the edge in G or G' to form a triangle is not independent since two adjacent triangles in G might share the edge

Doesn't matter. The sum of expectations is the expectation of the sum regardless of correlation, so you can reason about the triangles individually. (Higher moments, were you concerned about analyzing the estimation quality of this algorithm, would be trickier.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know what the estimation quality means. All the information and requirements I have is in the question.

Comment: @Dream_Big_In_Him If you wanted to know the variance of the estimate, for example.